# rtweet create_token missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, linux, twitter, centos7, rtweet

So I have been collecting tweets for some months on an external Linux Centos 7.6.1810 server but for some reasons, I can not do it anymore.

So my code is

```
consumer_key = 'xxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxx'
access_token = 'xxx'
access_secret = 'xxx'

options(httr_oauth_cache=T)
rtweet::create_token(
  app = "appname",
  consumer_key = consumer_key,
  consumer_secret = consumer_secret,
  access_token = access_token,
  access_secret = access_secret)
```

It has been working fine for months but some reasons, now I get the error

> Error in if (file == "") stop("'file' must be non-empty string") :
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

If i look at the parameters of the function `create_token`, the only parameter that I haven't put is `set_renv` but even with that parameter, it does not work.
However, it work fine on my local windows computer... any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.

The culprit was the file `.rtweet_token.rds` which is created every time the authentication is required. Actually, if the file already exists, then a new file is created by appending a number to it (`.rtweet_token1.rds` , `.rtweet_token2.rds`, etc).

It happened that I already had 1000 instances of these files and for some reason a new file was not being created.

The solution was to delete all the instances of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the file .rtweet_token.rds did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete ALL of the `.rtweet_token.rds` files which you can do.

If you are in RStudio, you can go to Files, Home, More, and Show Hidden Files. You will then see all of files. Delete them all and then it will work again.